# "...to stay safe." Who will stay safe here?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is a sentence:

> Alax feed the dog every day **to stay safe.**

My question is that **who is expected to stay safe here.**

**Is Alex feeding his dog to stay safe himself** or **is he doing so to keep his dog safe?**

Can it mean the both and I should understand from the context?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Alax feed the dog every day to stay safe.

If we bring forward the adverbial infinitive 'to stay safe', it becomes clear.

'To stay safe, Alax feeds the dog every day.'

Alex is feeding his dog to stay safe himself.

Answer (score 1):

With Alex as subject, and using the phrase "stay safe", it refers to Alex's safety.

To refer to the safety of the dog, it should be expressed like this:

Alex feeds his dog every day **to keep it safe.**

Comment: Okay, but I saw a sentence: "God gives us serenity to stay calm in times of difficulties." Here God doesn't want to stay calm.

Comment: In any case the sentence has a different structure. It means "God gives us serenity **for us** to stay calm in times of difficulties." There, the implied subject of the phrase "to stay calm" is "us". In your OP, it is clearly not the dog that has the purpose to stay safe. And again, if it were simply God's purpose to make us calm, it would be expressed "keep us calm".

Comment: And, are you sure it didn't say "God **give** us the serenity to stay calm in times of difficulties."? That would be a prayer asking for God to give us serenity for **us** to stay calm.

Comment: it needs a comma after "God", doesn't it.

Comment: I think usage is mixed on that point.

Comment: @user100323: Compare *He gave me money [**for me**] to buy food* and *He gave me money [**for him**] to show generosity.* Such constructions can be ambiguous as regards who the *[in order] **to*** refers to.